# how to get a total sum which is having both addition and subtraction sign in bash?

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I am having a file a.txt from that i grep a line start with A and cut 3 to 7 index character and try to sum them but problem is that it is also having (-) sign how I am able to do that.

I am working on linux server and tried many script but not able to find a solution.

and using this code its doing addition but i also want to do subtraction according to sign

```
grep "^A" a.txt |cut -c3-7 |awk '{SUM += $1} END {print SUM}'
```

original file contains:

```
A05000+
B05005-
C05845+
A05007-
A05648+
```

Should evaluate like:

`5000+ 5007- 5648`, resulting in `4359`.

Expexted output:
5641

getting Output:
15655

Comment: Curious to know how come the expected output is `4359`? `5000 -5007 +5648`, should evaluate to `5641`.

Comment: Are the "+" and "-" signs at the end of each term supposed to indicate the sign of *that* term, or whether to add or subtract the *next* term? In other words, if the file had just "A05000-" and "B05005+", would that mean -5000 +5005, or 5000-5005?

Comment: you are right output will 5641 only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one `awk` variation.

```
awk '/^A/ {s+=substr($1,7,1) substr($1,2,5)} END {print s}' file
5641

+5000+-5007+5648=5641
```

Comment: 5641 is right output by mistake i write 4359 thanks

Comment: @Prashant Updated my post to reflect correct sum.  Give a up-vote or accept an answer as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo $(( $(grep '^A' file | cut -c 3-)0 ))
4359
```

Basically what we do here is use the bash builtin arithmetic functions `$(( expr ))` to do the computation. I made use of the OP's command and added an extra 0 to the end to complete the last operation.